# How to speed up the Mixed-Integer Quadratic Program process?

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

Currently, I am solving a problem in the format:

$$\min_X X^TGX \\ s.t. \vec{1}X=M,x_i\in\{0,1\},\forall x_i\in X$$

$M$ is an integer as well. The problem that troubles me is that $X$ is a vector in $\{0,1\}$ with a size of $7000$. I use the solver in https://github.com/oxfordcontrol/miosqp. It seems they are using the branch-and-bound algorithm. And they claim the speed is comparable to Gurobi.

Is there a way to speed this calculation process up? It already took me 10 hours and I still can not get a solution. The parameters I can find to set the solver are the "integer feasibility tolerance", the "maximum number of iterations" and whether to use the "depth-first" rule or the "depth-first until the first incumbent and then best bound" rule.

I am totally new to the Mixed-Integer Quadratic Program so I don't know what these parameters mean. Is there a way to speed it up if I don't require a very accurate solution? Of course, I still don't want the solution to be a very bad. But I can tolerate the solver to get a solution within an hour.

Comment: This is a very large MIQP so it probably won't be easy to solve.  In your 10 hour run, did you get progress reports on the value of the best integer solution found and lower bound on the optimal value?  These can help you see how close you are to solving the problem.

Comment: Wouldn't we all love to know how to solve these problems faster?

Comment: Since all variables are 0/1 you could linearize the problem

Comment: Unless $Q$ is sparse, the linearized problem would have $7000 \times 6999 / 2 = 24,496,500$ variables, which would be a very large MILP.  There's little point in using the linearization approach if you have access to a solver like Gurobi that has MIQP support built in.

Comment: For a problem of this size, it may be worth looking into software packages for MIQP that have functionality for parallelization. MIQP is outside my area of expertise, but the most scalable algorithms in most scientific computing contexts are so because they can efficiently parallelize to either many CPUs or GPUs. You may be able to cut down your 10+ hours even with multiple cores on your machine depending on what algorithms are out there